# Skip data files while reading input and writing output in matlab code

Tags: matlab

I use matlab code to read several files and write output in the following way:

```
n=202;
for idx = 0:n

    infilename = sprintf('pt%d.txt',idx);
    outname = sprintf('out%d.txt',idx);
```

Now if some arbitrary data files are missing e.g. pt20.txt, pt50.txt ,etc then the code is terminated. I would like to modify the code in a way that if some data files are not found then the code would skip them and proceed to reading/writing the next available data file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also test existence of the file using [exist](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html)

```
n=202;
for idx = 0:n
    infilename = sprintf('pt%d.txt',idx);
    outname = sprintf('out%d.txt',idx);
    if exist( infilename , 'file') == 2
        do your stuff
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it does not work and it has syntax error. However, if I try infilename = sprintf('pt%d.txt',idx);
if exsit(infilename)  then the code is terminated once it encounters the missing data file. So, if for example, the 8th data file is missing then it writes outputs before encountering the missing data file and them terminates.

Comment: It should works. If file not exists, the for loop continue the job. Could you provide rest of your cde to understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I guess, previously there was a typo where there was a missing inverted comma after "file" . I just noticed you edited that part and I never noticed the missing ' . That's my bad. This is working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try something like [this (see how to handle exceptions heading)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/respond-to-an-exception.html).

```
for x:y
 try
   % do something ...
   break;
 catch
   fprintf('error occurs, retry...')
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But this didn't solve the problem. Thanks for the link